# Display the short or full version of text

Tags: javascript, html, css

By default the `short` version of element should be displayed (one line with `...`).
All items should be always displayed in the same version (`short` or `long` ).

1. If all are in the `short` version mode - Clicking on one item should display a `long` version of each element, the height of all elements should be the same and should be equal to the height of the highest element.
2. If all are in the `long` version mode - Clicking on one element should display a `short` version of each element (one line with `...`).

I created a code:

```js
                $(document).on("click", ".elementText", function (e) {
                    if($( this ).css( "-webkit-line-clamp" ) == "1"){
                        $(this).css("-webkit-line-clamp", "99");
                        var elementHeight = $(this).css( "height" );
                        $($(this).parent()).find(".elementText").each(function(){
                            $(this).css("-webkit-line-clamp", "99");
                            if($(this).css( "height" ) < elementHeight){
                                $(this).height(elementHeight);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else{
                        $(this).css("-webkit-line-clamp", "1");
                        var elementHeight = $(this).css( "height" );
                        $($(this).parent()).find(".elementText").each(function(){
                            $(this).css("-webkit-line-clamp", "1");
                            if($(this).css( "height" ) > elementHeight){
                                $(this).height(elementHeight);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    
                });
```

```css
.elementText{
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 5px;
  width:200px;
  background:yellow;
  float:left;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elementText">
  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text
</div>

<div class="elementText">       
  It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.      
</div>

<div class="elementText">           
  The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here',
</div>
```

It works if the `make long` (the first click after page load) click and `make short` (the second click after page load) click are on the same element.
The problem exists if the `make long` (the first click after page load) click and `make short` (the second click after page load) click are on the different elements. For example `make long` click is on the third element and the `make short` click is on the first element. Something goes wrong and the first and the second text are not cut correctly.

Why it does not work and what should I change to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem was: You set the height for long/short version on the heigth of the clicked element. But you have enlarge all of them and look for the maximum height and set the height in a second step for all of them to **max**.
For getting the shortversion set the height to **auto**, so all will display the needed 1 line. If there should be really after this differences at the height because of different font-sizes you could do here the step with max afterwards again.

I'm not sure if this is really necessary but you can test it: You can use a global variable and store there if long is displayed or not. At each change via click toggle the long-variable. If you want you could use instead a class which you are adding and removing to a HTML-element.

```js
var long = false;

$(document).on("click", ".elementText", function (e) {
             if(!long){
                long=true;
                let max = 0;
                $(this).css("-webkit-line-clamp", "99");
                $($(this).parent()).find(".elementText").each(function(){
                    $(this).css("-webkit-line-clamp", "99");
                    max = Math.max(max, parseInt($(this).css( "height" )) );
                });
                $($(this).parent()).find(".elementText").each(function(){
                    $(this).height(max);
                });
            }
            else{
                long=false;
                $(this).css("-webkit-line-clamp", "1");
                $(this).height('auto');
                $($(this).parent()).find(".elementText").each(function(){
                    $(this).css("-webkit-line-clamp", "1").height('auto');
                });
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <style> 
            .elementText{
                overflow: hidden;
                text-overflow: ellipsis;
                display: -webkit-box;
                -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
                -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
                cursor: pointer;
                padding-left: 5px;
                width:200px;
                background:yellow;
                float:left;
                margin:5px;
            }           
        </style>        
    </head>
        <body>
    
        <div class="elementText">
            Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text
        </div>
        
        <div class="elementText">       
            It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.        
        </div>
        
        <div class="elementText">           
            The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here',
        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I created local vairiable instead of global and set the value to 'var long = $(this).css("-webkit-line-clamp") == "99";'. looks great, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario, I would really advise you to use classes. Rather `toggle` classes than setting the actual css most of the time.

The idea here was to always get the largest `height` of the 3 elements, which is strictly based on their content after expanding them. So that's where the problem was.

Here is my approach on this:

```js
(function(){
  var display_element = $(".elementText");
  
  function getLargestHeight(elemArray)
  {
    // if there's no elements parsed, then no elements are expanded
    if(elemArray.length <= 0)
      return "auto";
      
    var rempResult = 0;
    
    $.each(elemArray,(i, e) => {
      let _e_height = parseInt($(e).css("height").slice(0,-2));
      
      if(_e_height > rempResult)
        rempResult = _e_height;
    });
    
    return rempResult + "px";
  }
  
  display_element.on("click", (e) => {
    if(display_element.hasClass("expanded"))
      display_element.removeClass("expanded");
    else
      display_element.addClass("expanded");
     
    $.each(display_element, (i, e) => {
      $(e).css("height", getLargestHeight($(".expanded")));
    });
  });
})();
```

```css
.elementText{
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 5px;
  width:200px;
  background:yellow;
  float:left;
  margin:5px;
  height: auto;
}

.expanded
{
  -webkit-line-clamp: 99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="elementText">
  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text
</div>

<div class="elementText">       
  It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.      
</div>

<div class="elementText">           
  The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here',
</div>
```